# How to add a shortcut to a button in the homescreen of the phone using Codename One?

Tags: button, codenameone, homescreen, home-screen-widget

I am trying to develop an application in Codename One where I have built a form to accept name, phone number, address and save all these information to the persistent storage using a submit button. Now the problem is to save all these details the user has to open the application and press the "add new details" button, only then the user can enter the values. Is it possible to add a shortcut of the "add new details" button on the homescreen so that the user don't need to open the application every time he/she tries to add a new entry? The user will just click on the "add new details" button present on the homescreen of his/her phone.

I am trying to develop this application for android, iOS and windows platforms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS doesn't have a "home screen" and shows the apps directly. Windows has a more unique tile approach where it isn't quite shortcuts.

You can use [native interfaces](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) to do this on the various OS's but the gist of this is that this isn't portable functionality so it's outside the domain of Codename One.

Comment: In case of android, for example the application clean master, after installing it a new shortcut other than the clean master application shortcut, appears on the home screen which can be used to clean the junk files directly without having to open the application and press the clean junk button. Is it possible to create such shortcuts using codename one (for android phones)? And can you tell me more about native interfaces? How to use them? Forgive me if i have asked something stupid, i am very new to codename one. So i am not quite familiar with it.

Comment: [This video](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) includes a brief introduction to native interfaces you can dig deeper in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) where we discuss the build hints and native interfaces in depth

Comment: Thank you Shai. If i have any more doubts i will post a comment here.